# run query by refreshing page or using crontab

Tags: php, arrays, forms, function

I was created a script today for forwarding email address by php.
It's working fine helped by a form.

there is a submit button in my script, while I click submit button it's sending mail to specified email address.

but I want to do that by refreshing the page http://gonplay.info/time/index.php

> I'm verry new in PHP, please check my script and help in details.

**Sorry for Bad English and Thanks in advance.**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>imap_check</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
     //check for new messages

     $mailbox = imap_open("{pop.gmail.com:995/pop/ssl}INBOX",
             "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com","PASSWORD");

     // Check messages
     $check = imap_check($mailbox);

     // show headers for messages

     $index=1;


      $header = imap_header($mailbox, $index);

  //Extract TO Name and Address
  $to = $header->to;
  foreach ($to as $id => $object) {
      $toname = $object->personal;
      $toaddress = $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host;
}     
  //Extract Sender Name and Address
  $from = $header->from;
  foreach ($from as $id => $object) {
      $fromname = $object->personal;
      $fromaddress = $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host;
}
  $subject=$header->Subject;
      $message = imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$index,1);

     imap_close($mailbox);

$rets = "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"POST\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"parse_var\" value=\"Mail\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"toname\" value=\"$toname\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"toaddress\" value=\"$toaddress\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fromname\" value=\"$fromname\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fromaddress\" value=\"$fromaddress\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"subject\" value=\"$subject\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"message\" value=\"$message\">";
    $rets .= "<input type=\"Submit\" name=\"Submit\" Value=\"Submit\"></form>";
    echo $rets;

 if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "Mail"){
$toname = $_POST['toname'];
$toaddress = $_POST['toaddress'];
$fromname = $_POST['fromname'];
$fromaddress = $_POST['fromaddress'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = <<<EOD
$message
EOD;

//Email to
$to = "$toname <joyahm@gmail.com>";// Change with your email address.

//Email Subject
$subject = "$subject";// Change with your email subject.

//Email Header
$headers = "From: $fromname <$fromaddress>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$success = mail("$to", "$subject", "$body", "$headers");
}
?>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a php question, but rather a unix/windows, (or whatever server you are using), question.

You can setup a cron job to call the page or run a script at regular intervals.

**EDIT**

Remove the code

```
$rets = "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"POST\">";
....
```

Remove the if statement, (but not the content).

```
if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "Mail"){
  ....
}
```

Hardcode the values, (previously inside the if statement)

```
$toname = 'whatever';
$toaddress = 'whatever';
$fromname = 'whatever';
$fromaddress = 'whatever';
$subject = 'whatever';
$message = 'whatever';
...
$success = mail("$to", "$subject", "$body", "$headers");
```

And that's all.

Comment: sorry to see that you didn't understand my problem, I wanna to know that how to bypass that form what I'm using currently.

eg. receive & send mail by only refreshing the page.

Comment: Ok, I edited it with what you need to do, basically remove the <form> as it is not needed anymore, and replace the $_POST values with whatever value you want to use.